# Как сделать пагинацию на каждом слайде Swiper JS

Tags: javascript, swiper

Нужна помощь, ломаю голову, загуглил по разному и не нашел ничего.
Проблема в следующем, возможно ли вообще на swiper.js сделать так, чтобы пагинация dots была не вынесена отдельно, а наоборот, приклеена к каждому слайду.
Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать `renderBullet` для пагинации на каждом слайде Swiper JS:

```
let swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    clickable: true,
    renderBullet: function (index, className) {
      return '<span class="' + className + '">' + (index + 1) + '</span>';
    },
  },
});
```

https://swiperjs.com/types/interfaces/types_modules_pagination.paginationoptions#renderbullet